# NetLogo: reporters not reporting correctly by turtle breed

Tags: netlogo, reporters

I have the following chunk of code:

```
to volver-a-casa
   (ifelse estado < 6 or estado = 8
      if donde != 1 [
        move-to mi-casa
        set donde 1
        set nro-personas nro-personas + 1     
        set color color + 10
      ]
   estado = 7 [
     set nro-personas nro-personas - 1
     set nro-fallecidos nro-fallecidos + 1
     set nro-fallecidos1 count personas1 with [estado = 7]
     set nro-fallecidos2 count personas2 with [estado = 7]
     set nro-fallecidos3 count personas3 with [estado = 7]
     set nro-fallecidos4 count personas4 with [estado = 7]
     move-to mi-casa
     set fallecidos fallecidos + 1
     die
   ]
  )
```

In my infectious disease model, I have 4 breeds of turtles (*personas1, personas2,* etc.) where *estado* is a turtle variable with 9 different categories or "states". The turtles transition to different states (*estado*) as they move been different types of patches (work, school, home). For each breed, there is a global reporter variable nropersonas that counts the number of turtles with *estado* = 7. I also attempted to construct separate global reporter variables (*nrofallecidos1, nrofallecidos2,* etc.) to count the number of turtles **by breed** that have estado = 7. *nropersonas* successfully counts the total number of turtles at each tick that has estado = 7, but my breed-specific reporter variables, *nrofallecidos1, nrofallecidos2, etc.*, are not reporting at all (turtle count is 0 across all reporters).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Can you please revise your question after having gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Especially for what concerns "Help others reproduce the problem". Also, please format your code as code by using the ``` that you find below the text box when you write your question. These elements will help you get helped.

Comment: Hi Matteo. Yes, I will attempt to revise my question accordingly. Sorry about that, I'm relatively new to using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed two things:

1. When you use `ifelse`, you only have to state the condition for the first case (`estado < 6 or estado = 8` in your case). The contrary (`estado = 7`) is implicated by logic and has to be deleted from your code. In the code below, I kept it as a comment.
2. To be more clear about what happend, you can add more square brackets. I like to have opening and closing brackets at the same level, but that's a style question.

Correct syntax is:

```
to volver-a-casa
ifelse estado < 6 or estado = 8
[
  if donde != 1 
  [
    move-to mi-casa
    set donde 1
    set nro-personas nro-personas + 1     
    set color color + 10
  ]
]
[
  ; in this case estado is 7
  set nro-personas nro-personas - 1
  set nro-fallecidos nro-fallecidos + 1
  set nro-fallecidos1 count personas1 with [estado = 7]
  set nro-fallecidos2 count personas2 with [estado = 7]
  set nro-fallecidos3 count personas3 with [estado = 7]
  set nro-fallecidos4 count personas4 with [estado = 7]
  move-to mi-casa
  set fallecidos fallecidos + 1
  die
]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Apologies, I should have also indicated that in my full code, after the conditional statement, there are multiple statements to execute, where: estado = 6....estado = 7...estado = 9...etc.